Confused on why regular conditional probabilities don't always exist
The book I'm reading defines P(F|G) as E[$I_F$|G]. It also states, using linearity of conditional expectations and monotone convergence theorem for conditional expectations, that P($\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty F_n|G) = \sum P(F_n|G)$ for a fixed disjoint sequence of events $F_n$ (a.s). He then states that because there are usually an uncountable amount of such disjoint sequences, we cannot say in general that a regular conditional probability exists, but to me it seems like that statement forces the conditional probability to satisfy countable additivity for any disjoint sequence and so it must always be a regular conditional probability. I attached a photo of the page I'm reading with more details (and a sketch of a proof I made on the right). 
Why does this not work? Thank you!

This is my understanding: For any sequence of disjoint sets, there exists a null set $A_\alpha$. But the number of this kind of sequences can be uncountable, so the number of those null sets  can be uncountable, then the probability P($\bigcup_{\alpha}A_\alpha$) can be non-zero. The result is countable additivity may not hold with a non-zero probability. Then in (b2), $F\mapsto P(w,F)$ may not be a measure for almost every $\omega$.
